# Нарушается вывод printf

Tags: c, ассемблер

Выполняю лабораторку в универе. Программу на си с вставкой на ассемблере в *Visual Studio* написал, но теперь ломаю голову, почему на операторе *printf* после ассемблерного кода выводится

> Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x00965CB1 в ConsoleApplication3.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу 0xFFFFFFFF.

printf до ассемблерного кода выполняется. Причём похожий код товарища на моём компьютере работает без косяков.

Сам код:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<locale>
#include <windows.h>
#define N 10

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int B[N];
    int R[N];
    int n = N, k = 0, pgseq = 0, count = 2;
    printf("Введите элементы массива, состоящего из %d элементов: \n", N);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf_s("%d", &B[i]);

    _asm {
        lea esi, B
        mov ecx, n
        mov edi, esi

        readFirst :
        mov esp, count
            cmp k, esp
            jl greaterseq
            dec ecx
            cmp ecx, 0
            jl startcopy
            mov eax, [esi]
            mov edi, esi
            jmp readSecond
            greaterseq :
        mov k, esp
            mov pgseq, edi
            dec ecx
            cmp ecx, 0
            jl startcopy
            mov eax, [esi]
            mov edi, esi
            jmp readSecond
            readSecond :
        dec ecx
            cmp ecx, 0
            jl startcopy
            mov count, 2
            add esi, 4
            mov ebx, [esi]
            cmp ebx, eax
            jl less
            jg greater
            jmp readSecond
            less :
        mov edx, 21
            jmp readOther
            greater :
        mov edx, 12
            jmp readOther
            readOther :
        dec ecx
            cmp ecx, 0
            jl startcopy
            add esi, 4
            mov eax, ebx
            mov ebx, [esi]
            cmp ebx, eax
            jl lesscmp
            jg greatercmp
            je interupt
            lesscmp :
        cmp edx, 21
            jl interupt
            inc count
            jmp readOther
            greatercmp :
        cmp edx, 12
            jg interupt
            inc count
            jmp readOther
            interupt :
        add ecx, 2
            sub esi, 4
            jmp readFirst
            startcopy :
        lea esi, R
            inc k
            mov ecx, k
            jmp finalloop;
    copy:
        mov edi, pgseq
            mov ebx, [edi]
            mov[esi], ebx
            add pgseq, 4
            add esi, 4
            finalloop :
            loop copy
    }
    char * mod = (char *)"убывающая";
    if (R[0] < R[1]) mod = (char *)"возрастающая";

    //дальше возникает исключение
    printf("Максимальная %s последовательность", mod);
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        printf("%d ", R[i]);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: как вариант вы вышли за пределы массива и щупаете чужую память

Answer (score 3):

Ну так что ж вы творите

```
mov esp, count
```

?

Регистр `esp` - это не регистр общего назначения. Это *указатель стека*, неявно использующийся в этой роли всеми стековыми инструкциями процессора (`push`, `pop`, `call` и т.п.). Как только вы уничтожили содержимое этого регистра, все, что зависит от стека, перестало работать. В вашем случае накрывается медным тазом подготовка (помещение в стек) параметров для вызова `printf`.

Теоретически регистром `esp` можно "на минутку" воспользоваться для своих целей, при условии, что потом вы восстановите его правильное значение, но обычно оно того не стоит и никакого смысла в этом нет.

Comment: Спасибо, всё стало понятно